# How to drop audio clips in Microsoft Visual Studio from Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging

I am working on the tank tutorial for Unity from Boston 2015. The part that is not working for me is dragging the audio clip on the variable names in the Microsoft Visual Studio file.

When I drag the audio file, and hover it over the variable name, the variable name lights up.

After, I drop the audio clip, and then itunes opens up and a tank engine is heard for 10 seconds. There is no indication of drag and drop to be effective?

My question is should I be using another text editor, and how do I correctly link the audio clip to the variable?

I am using windows 10 for Unity

Comment: Yes, I did thank you. I was confused because I havent been used to Unity. I need a cook Book or some sort, if that makes sense.

Comment: This site should do that automatically, that was weird.

Comment: Right, you have ot do it manually.  Thanks @chrisRathjen !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an audio to a Unity scene,

1) make a **.wav** file.

2) put that in your Unity assets folder.

3) open Unity.

4) drag that audio file from Project in to Hierarchy.

That's it.  "Microsoft Visual Studio" is unrelated.  You must Quit "Microsoft Visual Studio", ensure it is not running.